# How to enable two view controllers in the same window

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to develop a slide menu in my application which should open the menu view from the left (or the right) depending on the swipe direction.

What I did till now:

1- Create a main View Controller A

2- Create left (or right) View Controller B

3- When Slide button tapped, add B ViewController as a sub View for the A View Controller. [image: Left Slide Menu]

4- here's my code:

```
CGRect currentLeftFrame  = self.leftVC.view.frame;
    currentLeftFrame.origin  = CGPointMake(-1.0f * self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0f);
    self.leftVC.view.frame   = currentLeftFrame;
    [self addChildViewController:self.leftVC];
    [self.view addSubview:self.leftVC.view];
    [self.leftVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The problem is that buttons in the B View controller are not clickable.

Do one know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't add UIViewController as a a subview to your main viewcontroller. If you want to add a subview use B as a UIView.

Comment: google for UIViewController containment.

Comment: View controller A is not passing on touch messages to View controller B.  You need to tell both they have a parent/child. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31982623/3985749) for the requisite code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried indeed this solution, I thought that was the unique, but it does not work:
PS: I updated my post to put my code.

Comment: @Ali I think you may have the same ancillary problem as the OP in the question I linked in my comment above (see the comments on my answer): your B view controller is outside of the bounds of the parent (A) view controller, and does not receive the touch events.  Test by changing the frame of B so it definitely falls inside A, and see whether you get the touches.

Answer (score -1):

Use UIView for slide panel and add the slide view as subview on viewController's view or on app window.

Comment: I just don't understand some people intention to downvote.. What's wrong with my answer?